# Math Tutor sending correct variable and attempted variable to second class

Tags: java

I am supposed to create a math tutor. I was able to create one that works fine according to the instructions. However, I'm supposed to collect the number of attempts and number of problems correct and send them to a second class. Then calculate the number of attempts using a fuction and calculate the number correct problems using a function. Figure a score and display that information.

```
public class Math_Tutor 
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int choice;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName(name);
        
        do
        {
            System.out.println("*** Math Tutor Menu ***");
            System.out.println(
            "Choose the type of problem:\n" +
            "1. Addition\n" +
            "2. Subtraction\n" +
            "3. Multiplication\n" +
            "4. Exit"
            );
            
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1: 
                    addition();
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    subtraction();
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    multiplication();
                    break;
                }
                
        } while (choice!=4);
        
        student.results();

    }
    
    public static void addition()
    {
        int keepGoing;
        
        do 
        {
            int firstNum = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            int secondNum = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            int add = firstNum + secondNum;
            
            System.out.println(firstNum + " + " + secondNum + " ?");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int addInput = input.nextInt();

            if (addInput == add)

            System.out.println("Correct!");
            
            else

            System.out.println("Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is "+ add);

            System.out.println("Would you like to keep going?\n"
                    + "1. Yes\n"
                    + "2. No");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            keepGoing=input.nextInt();
            
        } while (keepGoing != 2);
    }
    
    public static void subtraction()
    {
        int keepGoing;

        do 
        {
            int firstNum = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            int secondNum = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            if (firstNum < secondNum)
            {
                int temp = firstNum;
                firstNum = secondNum;
                secondNum = temp;
            }
            int subtract = firstNum - secondNum;
            System.out.println(firstNum + " - " + secondNum + " ?");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int subInput = input.nextInt();

            if (subInput == subtract)

            System.out.println("Correct!");

            else

            System.out.println("Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is "+ subtract);

            System.out.println("Would you like to keep going?\n"
                    + "1. Yes\n"
                    + "2. No");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            keepGoing=input.nextInt();
       
        } while(keepGoing != 2);
    }
    
    public static void multiplication()
    {
        int keepGoing;

        do 
        {
            int firstNum = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            int secondNum = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            int multiply = firstNum * secondNum;
            System.out.println(firstNum + " * " + secondNum + " ?");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int multInput = input.nextInt();

            if (multInput == multiply)

            System.out.println("Correct!");

            else

            System.out.println("Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is "+ multiply);

            System.out.println("Would you like to keep going?\n"
                    + "1. Yes\n"
                    + "2. No");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            keepGoing=input.nextInt();
       
        } while(keepGoing != 2);
    }
    
}
```

Here is the second class

```
public class Student 
{   
        private String student;
        private int attempted;
        private int correct;
        private int score;
        
        
    public String setName(String name)
    {
        student = name;
        return student;
        
    }
    
    public int attempted(int attempt)
    {
        attempted = attempt;
        return attempted;
    }
    
    public int correct(int right)
    {
        correct = right;
        return correct;
    }
    
    public void results()
    {
        System.out.print("*** Results for " + student + " ***");
//        System.out.print("Total number of problems attempted: " + attempted);
//        System.out.print("Total number of problems correct: " + correct);
//        score = (correct / attempted) * 100;
//        System.out.print(student + " scored : " + score);
//        if (score >= 90)
//            System.out.print("Great work " + student);
//        else if (score >= 80 && score < 90)
//            System.out.print("Good work " + student);
//        else if (score >= 70 && score < 80)
//            System.out.print("Not bad " + student);
//        else 
//            System.out.print("Keep trying");
        
    }
}
```

I have to count the number of attempts and the number of problems gotten right in the add, subtract, and multiply functions and send these numbers to the student class. I have tried to create variables in several places to send the counts to the main class so I can send them over but nothing works.

Comment: This is not framed in a question what specifically are you having difficulty with and what have you tried so far to get it working?

Comment: I have to count the number of attempts and the number of problems gotten right in the add, subtract, and multiply functions and send these numbers to the student class. I have tried to create variables in several places to send the counts to the main class so I can send them over but nothing works.

Comment: I have edited your question, adding your comment to clarify the question for those who complained about its unclarity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `student` object, which you create in method `main`, can be accessed from your `addition()`, `substraction()`, etc. methods.

To achieve this, you could pass the `student` object as parameter to these methods, or declare `student` as static variable on class `MathTutor`, like this:

```
public class MathTutor {
    private static Student student;
```

Next, in order to count attempts, you need to call your student's `attempted` and `correct` methods from within `addition()`, `substraction()`, and so on. I'd change these methods to something like this, so that they increase internal counters of the `student` object, e.g.:

```
public void addAttempt() {
    attempted++;
}
```

Then at the end, your `results()` method can print out results of a student, just like you did in your out-commented code.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an exercise I will refrain from solving it, but I will provide you the guidance you need to make sure you will be able to solve it.

Let's consider this class:

```
public class Foo {
    //...
    public int getSomeValue() {
        return 42; // you can use your own value instead, this is just an example
    }
    //...
    public Foo() {} //An empty constructor for the sake of simplicity
    //...
}
```

Now, let's consider another class

```
public class Bar {
    public void doSomething() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        int someValue = foo.getSomeValue();
        //Do something with someValue
    }
}
```

We have used a [getter](https://codehs.gitbooks.io/apjava/content/Classes-And-Object-Oriented-Programming/getter-and-setter-methods.html) inside `doSomething` in order to get some value from our `foo` instance of the `Foo` `class`. You can also define a `public` data-member, but it's not something I would recommend.

Back to your example: it's very good that you have a `public` setter called `setName`, but you will also need to differentiate data reading from data writing for managing the attempted and correct data. Currently you have two methods where the setter and getter features are messed up. Instead, you will need to have a `getAttempted` method to allow it to be read (this will be used from outside the class to get the attempted value) and a `setAttempted` value to change this value. You will need to follow the same pattern for correct. Then you will be able to properly set and get these values.